# Is this normal on ubuntu shutdown?

Tags: 19.10

Ubuntu shutdown screen shows Ubuntu loading dots for a while before shutting down.
[image: picture]

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: it doesnt cause any problems but seems weird, didnt get this on 18.04

Comment: It looks normal to me.

Comment: Depends on how long they last, should go black/off in much less than a minute.  Is it just three dots or you have five dots as usual?

Comment: Yep, that is normal

Comment: What you're describing/showing looks like a `plymouth` screen to me; it hides message (scary for end-users) and shows something moving (on bootup & shutdown). If you don't like that `plymouth` screen you can disable or change it.

Answer (score 1):

It is not abnormal to see the five dots screen when shutting down the computer. It happens occasionally on some computers, especially on slow computers. The five dots screen will show for less time or not show at all if you close all open windows before shutting down the computer, particularly open web browser windows.

Answer (score 1):

During boot up Ubuntu displays 5 cycling dots using a process called "Plymouth". You can have the same thing during shutdown but most people can't see it or it isn't installed:

- [plymouth does not show splash screen for shutdown and reboot](http://plymouth%20does%20not%20show%20splash%20screen%20for%20shutdown%20and%20reboot)

On my system I do not have a Shutdown Plymouth splash screen:

```
$ ll /lib/systemd/system/shutdown.target.wants
ls: cannot access '/lib/systemd/system/shutdown.target.wants': No such file or directory
```

I imagine on your system the results will be different. Further it would appear the difference occurred with the upgrade from 18.04 to 19.10.